# Temporary property for Laravel Eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel Eloquent model User, which has a table with username and email columns. I need to add a property for the model on runtime, something like $user->secure. This property doesn't need to go to database.

When i add this property and hit $user->save() i get an error saying i don't have database column 'secure'. I can unset 'secure' before save but somehow it feels there should be a better way to do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: The suggestion queue is full but I would like to just highlight `$user->secure` and `$user->save()`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just add an attribute to your class.

```
class User extends Eloquent {
  public $secure;

  // ...
}
```

Note that it is better to declare it protected and add corresponding accessors and mutators (`getSecure` and `setSecure` methods) to your model.

Comment: why make it `protected` and not `private` ?

Comment: AFAIK, some people prefer `protected` because it allows an extending class to access the property. They only use `private` when they're certain they never want a child class to to access it. It's especially convenient when you usually avoid inheritance anyway. Personally, I tend to use the smallest sope possible, and I open it up to `protected` when an actual need is discovered. That's mostly habit though, not a strong opinion. When I want to establish a clear contract, I'll put in the work of choosing more appropriate visibility. That includes using the `final` keyword too.

Answer (score 16):

For those who still find this post (like I did), you may need to explicitly declare the property as `null` to prevent it from being automatically added to the `attributes` array, and thus being added to INSERT/UPDATE queries:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public $secure = null;

    // ...
}
```

Source: http://laravel.io/forum/02-10-2014-setting-transient-properties-on-eloquent-models-without-saving-to-database

Answer (score 4):

If you intend to make use of that add-on property, then `$append` will blow your mind.

http://laraveldaily.com/why-use-appends-with-accessors-in-eloquent/