# How to use a protected property in an Eloquent model without Laravel trying to save it to the database

Tags: laravel, properties, model, attributes, eloquent

In one of my models, I have an attribute named "slug". When the slug is changed, I need to record the original slug before updating it to the new one, so my model has a protected property "originalSlug". Before saving the model, I do something like this in my model:

```
protected $originalSlug;

public function customSave($newSlug){
   $this->originalSlug = $this->slug;
   $this->slug = $newSlug;
   return $this->save();
}
```

Then I have an event that does other tasks using that originalSlug after a successful save.
The problem is Laravel is trying to save the originalSlug to the database though it isn't actually an attribute and doesn't have a database column. So it fails with the "Column not found" error.

What could I do to get Laravel to ignore that originalSlug property, or is there a better way I should be doing this?

Comment: Why don't you just raise the event before you call the save?

Comment: I only want the event to fire if the model has been successfully saved.

Comment: Yea you can raise the event, pass the old data as a DTO. Then only fire it after the model has saved successfully. This series might help: https://laracasts.com/series/commands-and-domain-events

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll look into that series. It's a bit over my head at the moment, but it might very well be the best way to do it.

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297240/temporary-property-for-laravel-eloquent-model/31082907#31082907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want `Eloquent` to ignore a property, it needs to be accessible to set, otherwise `__set` will be called and `Eloquent` will treat it as an attribute.
2. You can alternatively use `mutator` for this.

So here's what you need:

```
public $originalSlug;

public function customSave($newSlug){
   $this->originalSlug = $this->slug;
   $this->slug = $newSlug;
   return $this->save();
}
```

or:

```
protected $originalSlug;

public function customSave($newSlug){
   $this->originalSlug = $this->slug;
   $this->slug = $newSlug;
   return $this->save();
}

public function setOriginalSlugAttribute($value)
{
   $this->originalSlug = $value;
}
```

Then Eloquent will not set an originalSlug `attribute` , so it won't be saved to the db.

**You can do that with events, like suggested in the comments, and I would suggest this way too.**